# Wait till Animation Ends - jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am building a jQuery Slider for this specific project im working on. The problem I am having is that my code doesnt animate during the slide process. What it should do is, depending on the toggle side (left or right) it should go +100% right -100%. It Animates in exactly how I want it, but it doesnt "out" how it should.  here is a live version of it. dev.designsbycamaron.net

Jquery Code.

```
$('section#tf-ipad-info .listofimages .slide:first').addClass('activeslide').appendTo('#tf-ipad-info .mid ul li.mid-image');
        $('section#tf-ipad-info .left-click').click(function(){
            $('.activeslide').removeClass('activeslide').animate({right : "+=100%"}, { complete: function(){
                $('section#tf-ipad-info .listofimages .slide:first').addClass('activeslide').appendTo('#tf-ipad-info .mid ul li.mid-image').css({right : "-100%"});
                    $('section#tf-ipad-info .activeslide').animate({right : "0"} , {complete: function(){

                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            $('section#tf-ipad-info .mid-image .slide:first').appendTo('section#tf-ipad-info .listofimages').removeClass('activeslide').removeAttr('style');
        });
        $('section#tf-ipad-info .right-click').click(function(){
            $('.activeslide').animate({right : "-=100%"}, { complete: function(){
                $('section#tf-ipad-info .listofimages .slide:first').addClass('activeslide').appendTo('#tf-ipad-info .mid ul li.mid-image').css({right : "+100%"});
                    $('section#tf-ipad-info .activeslide').animate({right : "0"} , {complete: function(){

                        }
                    })
                }
            });
            $('section#tf-ipad-info .mid-image .slide:first').appendTo('section#tf-ipad-info .listofimages').removeClass('activeslide').removeAttr('style');
        });
```

HTML CODE

```
<ul class="tbl rotater-img-main-content t-align-center">

                                <li class="tbl-cell left-click">
                                    <img src="images/left-arrow-clicker.png" alt="arrow"/>
                                </li>
                                <li class="tbl-cell mid-image ">

                                </li>
                                <li class="tbl-cell right-click">
                                    <img src="images/right-arrow-clicker.png" alt="arrow"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: I don't know but, did you try the delay() ?

Comment: complete function should behave like a delay

Comment: I just checked FF and IE. This works. accept chrome